# MongoDB connection to remote server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ssh, remote-server

I am using a remote mongoDB server. When I connected with username and password using Robo3T It will successfully connected(ssh).

However when I use it in my node server it will gives following error.

Code

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://156.6*.***.***:22/TestDB',
{user:'root', pass:'********', useMongoClient: true} , 
error => {
console.log(error);
}
 );
```

Error

```
{ 
  err: 'socketHandler',
  trace: '',
  bin: undefined,
  parseState:
   { 
     sizeOfMessage: 759714643,
     bytesRead: undefined,
     stubBuffer: undefined
   } 
}
Unhandled rejection (<{"err":"socketHandler","trace":"","par...>, no stack trace)
```

I tried so many ways. But always it returns that error. How can I solve this problem?.

Comment: Maybe you should check rejected promise?

Comment: How can do it @modernator

Comment: `mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@/156.6*.***.***:22/TestDB')`

Comment: I don't know about *moongse*, however it seems like it uses promise. Add onrejected handler by using catch method.

Comment: @AmrAly I tried it. But it didn't work.  Only work for localhost in my scenario

Comment: Ok I'll check it @modernator

Comment: mine work by just adding  URL in a variable and using it in connect,  Wierd but works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `pass` to `password`

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.connect(
  'mongodb://156.6*.***.***:22/TestDB',
  {
    auth: {
      user:'root',
      password:'********',
    },
    useMongoClient: true
  },
  err => {
    console.log(err);
  },
);
```

I've also added a log to catch any error which may be thrown. Let us know the output of that if it doesn't work.

Comment: **mongoose.connect('mongodb://156.6*.***.***:22/TestDB',{user:'root', 
    password:'**********', useMongoClient: true}, 
    function(err, db) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log(db);
    }
}  );**

Comment: I slightly edited my answer to push the user/password within an `auth` object. Please try that and report back

Comment: Now it gives following error.  ** events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8089
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14) ...............
    **

Comment: Interesting I believe this error is not to do with Mongodb anymore. It looks like your trying to use port 8089, however that is being used by something else. Make sure to stop other programs / restart

Comment: Yes, I cleared process on the port. Now it give following error.

Comment: **Test API App listening on port 8085
{ err: 'socketHandler',
  trace: '',
  bin: undefined,
  parseState:
   { sizeOfMessage: 759714643,
     bytesRead: undefined,
     stubBuffer: undefined } }
Unhandled rejection (<{"err":"socketHandler","trace":"","par...>, no stack trace)**

Comment: what can be solution for this

Comment: I'm not sure @Amith, it doesn't look like it's a Mongoose issue at this point. I'd recommend making a new small project and testing with an example from their site and work backwards